# Как плавно повернуть объект до определённого угла unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию например на стрелку вправо, плавно происходил поворот **до** 90° и тп

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, new Quaternion(0, 90, 0, 0), t);
```

Пробовал сделать через quaternion lerp/slerp, информации нормальной почти нет, так и не понял как это работает. Даже кривую для получения "времени" создавал.

Кто знает как это сделать или может рассказать о кватернионах буду очень рад.

Comment: используй ассет LeanTween - через него можно плавно двигать, поворачивать за определенный промежуток времени. А если нужно, то и добавить эфекты на поворот вроде как будто бы на резинке болтается или подобное

Comment: Не очень хочется использовать целый ассет для решения одной задачи, но спасибо, на будущее пригодиться.

Comment: Лично я даный ассет использую практически в каждом проэкте. Он весьма сильно упрощает множество мелких задач. Я и сам противник добавления кучи ассетов, но даный - это просто маст хэв в практически любом проэкте.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше почитал об Quaternion и оказалось, что всё гораздо проще, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3) позволяет не мучатся и просто задавать параметры в градусах.

Comment: только за заданый промежуток времени это делается через него более заковыристо) Попробуй повернуть за промежуток времени в 7.5 секунд )

Comment: Если кому интересно чего я пытался добиться вот [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/g42qwoM4hMviqQ)
P.s - да графон топ.